# Is BCryptGetProperty call deterministic?

Tags: windows, winapi, encryption, visual-c++

Could someone answer one question, please?

Is the call **BCryptGetProperty** deterministic?
(should it return the same results for the same parameters in calls while running in one process?)
The idea is not to call the same function more than once for calculating hashes or encrypting.
I understand, that the result of SHA256 must have the same size, but there are elements less obvious (BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the size of a SHA256 hash is always the same. Getting the size by asking the crypto provider is useful if you are working at a higher level.

Imagine you have a generic hash class:

```
class Hash {
  bool Init(LPCWSTR pszAlgId) { BCryptGetProperty(m_AlgoProvider, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, ...); m_data = malloc(); ... BCryptCreateHash(..., pszAlgId, m_data, ...) ... }
  void AddData(LPCVOID p, SIZE_T cb) { ... }
  DWORD GetHashSize() { BCryptGetProperty(m_HashObj, BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH, ...); }
  bool Finalize(LPVOID pHash) { ... }
};
```

The class does not know the hash algorithm nor the hash size at compile time.

`BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH` is the size of the internal data used by the hashing function. It is the same for all hashes of a specific type implemented by a specific crypto provider. If you only support Windows 7 and later you can ask Windows to allocate this memory for you and you don't have to query the object size.

I believe all BCRYPT properties are deterministic after the crypto object has been properly created/initialized and you can cache obvious constant fields like sizes and modes. Things like `BCRYPT_INITIALIZATION_VECTOR` are obviously a per-object property and should only be cached for that specific object.

Comment: I highly appreciate the answer.